# Azure B2C in .Net Core API

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Currently I have .NET Core API and custom frontend and I am using msal.js for Azure B2C Authentication. I was looking if it is possible to move auth flow to my API where I will have my own routes /register /login and will send necessary information like email password etc, and then from API register user on Azure B2C without their popup form.

Does anyone have any resource on this or example.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-active-directory/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: what's the point of using azure b2c then?

Comment: @sidecus Point is that React library for AD B2C is useless. I tis buggy and does not work properly so I have to replace it with this approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web api are be used to protect and accept the b2c access tokens from client applications.

You can implement Azure AD B2C .Net Core MVC web application with web api. Please go through the available [code samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2) which can help you more.

If you are looking for registering the user using API you can make use [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api).